# Storing Blob files from my WCF to my SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, wcf

Well i have to have a WCF service that i will use to upload music to my Sql server database in a blob form. I have uploaded blobs to a sql database before but that was with asp.im not sure how it will be with a WCF.

I understand how to create the table that will accept varbinaryMAX but then what to do with the service and data contract in WCF.any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just define byte array as a parameter in one of the service operationons and on the client side, read the file into a byte array and pass it to the service.